# Errors when posting to a friends feed using FB iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

Some form of this has been asked/answered before but I'm still pretty hazy on the issue. I'm trying to post to a friends feed but keep getting "error com.facebook.sdk code = 5" errors when trying to use startWithGraphPath: from the new FB SDK for ios. The FBSession is active and open and the access_token appears to be correct... Here's some code:

```
    -(void)inviteUser:(NSString *)whoever {
        if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {
            // No permissions found in session, so ask for it
            [FBSession.activeSession reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                if (!error){        
                    [self sendInvite:whoever];
                }
            }    
        }];
     }

-(void) sendInvite:(NSString *)whoever {
    NSMutableDictionary *params =
        [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"A name of something", @"name",
        nil];

    [FBRequestConnection
         startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed", whoever]
         parameters:params
         HTTPMethod:@"POST"
         completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                             id result,
                             NSError *error) {
             NSString *alertText;
             if (error) {
                 alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                              @"error: domain = %@, code = %d",
                              error.domain, error.code];
             } else {
                 alertText = @"Posted successfully.";
             }
             // Show the result in an alert
             [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result"
                                         message:alertText
                                        delegate:self
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!"
                               otherButtonTitles:nil]
              show];
         }];
```

I'm still new at this, and am probably missing something basic. But I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I think there were two problems:

1. Not having the session properly communicated inside the app (i.e. I had the FBSession open in a loginController, but not in the sendInvite controller <- not the exact names, obviously). As a result, the access_token actually wasn't active. I should have followed the FB docs and put the FBSession methods in the appdelegate.
2. I was using "publish_action" permissions when I believe I should have been using "publish_stream."

Works smoothly with these two changes. I do have a follow-up question, though: how to post on someone else's wall using the new SDK's native share dialog? I'll probably ask this as a separate question.